# How to write to a file when you only have the filename?

Tags: python, file, recursion

```
def reverse_lines(n):
    with open(n,'r') as fie:
        data = fie.read().split('\n')
        if len(data)== 0:
            pass
        else:    
            print(data[0])
            ding = data[1::]
            fie = '\n'.join(ding)
    file(n).truncate()
    file(n).write(fie)
           
    return reverse_lines(n)
```

[image: The prompt]

I am struggling to write to the file because I only have the file name. I do not understand the interaction between what I return and the parameter it accepts.

Comment: Why is having the filename a reason not to be able to write to a file? What else do you need?

Comment: "You can assume the file exists and is readable"   ... what is your problem?

Comment: notice that you opened it with mode 'r' which is read only. It's going to be difficult to write to that handle.

Comment: if you do not have any path in the filename it will use the current dir its executed in

Comment: To write to the file, you need to open it in write-mode. Use a new block just like you did to read from the file: `with open(n,'w') as fie: #write operations here`

Comment: The instructions don't say that you're supposed to write to the file. You're just supposed to read the file, the result is printed on the terminal.

Comment: Looking at your code I suspect you get an error. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this recursively when the parameter is just the filename. A recursive function needs a base case based on the parameter, and it needs to pass a different parameter in the recursive call that gets it closer to the base case.

Comment: @Barmar: I can, but I can't answer now that the question has been closed.

Comment: Eh, it just says `reverse_lines` has to *accept* a `str` file name as an argument, not that it *only* accepts such an argument :) Open the file if you get a string, and pass the file-like object to the recursive calls.

Comment: Oh ... I get it now. This can have an internal recursive function which is hidden by the outer wrapper, which is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

This answer I consider poor because it abuses the parameters and also manually catches a `StopIteration`. Still it is recursive and produces the correct output:

```py
def reverse_lines(n, contents = None):
    if not contents:
        with open(n, 'r') as file:
            contents = (line.strip() for line in file)
            reverse_lines(n, contents)
    else:
        try:
            line = next(contents)
            reverse_lines(n, contents)
            print(line)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        
reverse_lines('poem.txt')
```

Output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make a `lines` generator that generates the lines of a given `filename` -

```py
def lines(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
      yield line.strip()
```

And a generic `reverse` generator that reverses any iterable, `it` -

```py
def reverse(it):
  stop = {}
  v = next(it, stop)
  if v is stop: return
  yield from reverse(it)
  yield v
```

Combine them for the desired effect -

```py
for line in reverse(lines("myfile.txt")):
  print(line)
```

Given `myfile.txt` -

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Output -

```
g
f
e
d
c
b
a
```